# Probability question - getting X jellybeans

Tags: probability

If I'm given a bag of jellybeans where I have for instance $x$ sweet ones, $y$ sour ones and $z$ mixed tasting ones, and the total amount is $x + y + z$ jellybeans, how many beans must I eat until I'm $100\%$ sure I've eaten $5$ beans of the same taste already?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $x,y,z\ge4$, then you can eat four of each, which means $12$ is not enough.

Comment: yeah but I need to find out HOW much i need for it to be enough

Comment: well, think about the hint. Apparently 12 is not enough, since then we can eat four of each. However, what happens if we eat 12 beans?

Comment: I meant 13 the second time...